# How is a process priority with R when starting a process with system() set

Tags: r, process

In a loop, I start processes from within R with the following function:

```
system(mycommand.exe, ... )
```

Is there an elegant way of setting the process priority of `mycommand.exe`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `psnice`.  If you use `fork` you can spawn a new pid.

```
psnice(pid = Sys.getpid(), value = NA_integer_)
system(mycommand.exe, ...)
```

or

```
new_pid <- fork(slave=NULL)
psnice(pid = new_pid, value = NA_integer_)
```

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/tools/html/psnice.html
http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/fork/html/fork.html

Comment: cheers, can't check it atm. Once I have, I will comment and accept answ. asap.